# Not able to post data using ajax in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello I have included given code in my view

```
= form_for @order, :url => update_express_shipping_path,:remote=> true, :html => { :id => "shippingDetails" } do |form|
    = form.radio_button :express_shipping, true, :value => true, :id => 'shipping_method4', :name => 'shipping_method'
    Express Shipping
    .checkOrder{:value=> @order.id}
```

and in my js file inlcuded

```
$('#shipping_method4').click(function(){ 
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        alert ('123')
        $.ajax({
            url: '/update_express_shipping',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'id': $('.checkOrder').attr('value'),
                'express_shipping': $(this).val()
              },
            contentType: 'json'  
        });     
    } 
})
```

and in my controller

```
def update_express_shipping
    byebug
    a = '123'
  end
```

Now when I click on radio button and it is checked so I am not receiving data in my controller it gives only this
params
{"controller"=>"spree/checkout", "action"=>"update_express_shipping"}

Please let me know where I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please put the log

Answer (score 1):

for radio buttons you should use change() instead of click()

replace

> $('#shipping_method4').click(function(){

with

> $('#shipping_method4').change(function(){

Comment: did you add only one radio button or more than one.
A form has to have more than one radio button.
If you are adding only one. You must mean to add check box instead of radio button.

With your reply I can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following syntax of [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

```
$.post('/update_express_shipping', { 'id': $('.checkOrder').attr('value'),
                'express_shipping': $(this).val()})
```